# memcpy of uint8_t to uint16_t

Tags: c++

I have a code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    uint8_t x[4] = {55, 11, 0, 20};
    uint16_t y;
    memcpy(&y, &x[0], 2);
    std::cout<<y<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

(hex of 55 - 37, hex of 11 - B)
in which I expect y to contain "37B"(i.e., - 891 in decimal). But, Y actually contains "B37"(i.e., 2871 in decimal). How to maintain the order with memcpy without endian swap operation.

Comment: [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

Comment: No matter the endianness, `37B` is out of the question - you've completely lost half of a byte then.

Comment: @PaoloM As you can see from the example, 2 elements of an array are copied into a single variable (that is 2 x size of array element). Your suggestion only assigns one array element.

Comment: http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: Aside: it would be much more readable just to write everything in hex and eschew talking about things in decimal. You can do this in code too: e.g. `{0x37, 0x0b, 0x00, 0x14}` and `std::cout << std::hex << y << std::endl;`.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti: Isn't it obvious from his comment that he probably already knows that?

Comment: Would this help ?:  std::cout<< ntohs(y)

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti: That was a rhetorical question...

Comment: @KarolyHorvath right...English language...what a stranger ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting `B37` is because you're on a little-endian machine.

The call to `memcpy` is doing what you would expect.  The value `0x37` is copied to the first byte of `y`, while `0x0B` is copied to the second byte of `y`.  And because you're on a little-endian architecture, the first byte of `y` is the least significant.  So it contains the value `0xB37`.

If you want `x[0]` to be the high byte and `x[1]` to be the low byte of `y`, you need to do it in a way that doesn't depend on endianness:

```
y = x[1];          // y = 0x0B
y |= x[0] << 8;    // y = 0x0B | 0x3700 = 0x370B
```

This will give `y` a value of `0x370B`.  However this is still not the `0x37B` value you expect.

If that's what you want, you need to recognize that `0x37B` has a value of `0x03` for the high byte and `0x7B` for the low byte.

So you would either need to define `x` as follows:

```
// note the use of hex constants to make the values more clear
uint8_t x[4] = {0x7b, 0x3, 0x0, 0x14};
```

Or you would need to perform some additional bit shifting to get the values you need:

```
y = x[1];          // y = 0x0B
y |= x[0] << 4;    // y = 0x0B | 0x370 = 0x37B
```

Answer (score 3):

`memcpy` copies memory. And it *does* maintain the order of the bytes of memory. You can't make `memcpy` do something else.

Your problem is that you don't want to copy memory; you want to do some particular arithmetic operation (e.g. concatenate two 8-bit values to get a 16-bit value).

Exactly how integer types are laid out in memory is unspecified behavior. On your CPU, your `memcpy` hack does not perform the arithmetic operation you want. Thus, to do what you want, have to do something other than (or in addition to) `memcpy`.

I advise doing the arithmetic operation with arithmetic operations: you'll get code you can be sure works on everything<sup>*</sup>, and your program will most likely perform similarly (or even better) than the hack anyways, especially with compiler optimizations turned on.

<sup>*: everything that has the relevant types, of course</sup>

Comment: Using shift/OR to make wider values from an array of bytes is sometimes called [Endian Agnostic code](http://commandcenter.blogspot.ca/2012/04/byte-order-fallacy.html).  And yes, it usually does optimize away when no endian conversion is needed.